# Event object eaten by jQuery animation callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have a problem with event object passed to the function in `drop` event. In my code, `div#dropArea` has it's drop event handled by `firstDrop` function which does some animations and then calls the proper function `dropFromDesktop` which handles the `e.dataTransfer.files` object. I need this approach in two separate functions because the latter is also used further by some other divs in the HTML document (no need to duplicate the code). First one is used only once, to hide some 'welcome' texts.

Generally, this mechanism lets you drag files from desktop and drop them into an area on my website.

Here's, how it looks (in a shortcut):

```
function firstDrop(ev) {
    var $this = $(this);

    //when I call the function here, it passes the event with files inside it
    //dropFromDesktop.call($this, ev);

    $this.children('.welcomeText').animate({
        opacity: '0',
        height: '0'
    }, 700, function() {
        $('#raw .menu').first().slideDown('fast', function() {
            //when I call the function here, it passes the event, but 'files' object is empty
            dropFromDesktop.call($this, ev);
        });
    });
}

function dropFromDesktop(ev) {
    var files = ev.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    (...) //handling the files
}

$('#dropArea').one('drop', firstDrop);
$('some_other_div').on('drop', dropFromDesktop);
```

The problem is somewhere in `jQuery.animation`'s callback - when I call my function inside it, the event object is passed correctly, but files object from dataTransfer is empty!

Whole script is put inside `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` so the order of function declarations doesn't matter, I guess.

Comment: make jsfiddle which show the problem

Comment: Why don't you keep a reference to `Event.dataTransfer.files` instead? This will solve your problem

Comment: It would, but notice that `dropFromDesktop` function is also called by an event handler for some other div. There, the whole `event` object is passed.

Comment: I doubt the event is being modified. But put `console.log(ev)` at various places and see if it's actually changing.

Comment: I did it and that's what stands in the question. I mean that's what I came up with.

Comment: I guess I'll just use Alexander's suggestion. That makes me add some more code inside `dropFromDesktop` to determine if parameter passed to the function is `event` or `FileList` but I guess that's the best for now.

Comment: I know its just very stupid .. but try changing the call for #dropArea as dropFromDesktop.call(ev,$this); instead of dropFromDesktop.call($this, ev);

Comment: The first parameter in `call` is always replacement for `this`. Tried your idea - didn't work.

Comment: @matewka, I meant modifying `dropFromDesktop` to receive a `FileList` and `some_other_div`'s binding though. Anyways, there are lot of ways

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your idea, could you please show me an example how to approach this? Is there a way to pass only a part of `event` in the binding?

Comment: Of course there are. I just wanted to provide the best one ;) Anyway, I get what you mean. I binded `some_other_div`'s with an additional function which pull's out `FileList` from `event` and then calls `dropFromDesktop` so the `dropFromDesktop` could receive a `FileList` both from `#dropArea` and `some_other_div`.

Comment: @matewka, yup, that was it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is related with the lifetime of the `Event` object. Unfortunately, I have no clue about the cause of it. But, there is a way to workaround it that I can think of and it is keeping a reference to `Event.dataTransfer.files` instead.

```
var handleFileList = function(fn) {
  return function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    return fn.call(this, evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);
  };
};
```

```
var firstDrop = function(fileList) { ... }
var dropFromDesktop = function(fileList) { ... }
```

```
$('#dropArea').one('drop', handleFileList(firstDrop));
$('some_other_div').on('drop', handleFileList(dropFromDesktop));​
```

Comment: Similiar to my recent approach but even better and more tidy.